# is there a definition on how to integrate a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

> Question:is there a definition on how to integrate a tensor?

It could be either covariant, contra variant or mixed tensors? I don't have an application of it in mind but just out of curiosity.

> Any leading literature on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Vectors are and matrices are both tensors. How do we integrate those? Termwise.

Comment: If $(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold and $T$ is a type $(r,s)$-tensor field, you can define $\int T:\Omega^1(M)^{\times r}\times \mathfrak{X}(M)^{\times s}$ to be the $\Bbb R$-linear map given by $$\left(\int T\right)(\theta^1,\ldots ,\theta^r,X_1,\ldots,X_s) = \int_M T_p(\theta^1(p),\ldots,\theta^r(p),X_1(p),\ldots,X_s(p))\,{\rm d}\mu_g(p),$$where ${\rm d}\mu_g$ is the measure induced by $g$. But I'm not sure if this is useful at all. The standard thing is to integrate differential $k$-forms over $k$-dimensional manifolds, to produce numbers.